# my vagrant server port is not working

Tags: python, flask, vagrant

I am building a small website in vagrant using flask. i ran the database setup python file and it worked perfectly and created the database. I also then setup and ran the server_setup.py file and it ran. it then showed that the server setup file was runnging and the port that it was running on was live at 8080. when i went on chrome and tested the connection by typing localhost:8080. it said the site cant be reached and i changed the port number but the same thing happened. can anyhone help me with this issue. i will have the server setup code below with the port number at the very bottom..

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Authorization, General_Info, Contact_Info, Projects, Project_Tools, Experience
from database_setup import Education, Skills, Certificates, Base

#Initialize the Flask App
app = Flask(__name__)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///website_oj.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = DBSession()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/testing')
def Testing():
    return render_template('testing.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = "Secret_Key"
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080)
```

this is the response i am getting from vagrant when i am running python server_setup.py

```
Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

but on chrome it says the site cant be reached...

Comment: Can you ping localhost? Have you tried in a different browser? May be cache related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your app on http://localhost:8080 from a browser running on the host OS (not the vagrant guest VM), you can setup Vagrant to [forward the port](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html), by using something like below in your `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
end
```

Above I've forwarded the guest VM's port 8080 to the same port number 8080 on the host, but it can be another port on the host.

Comment: That fixed the issue that you for that i just had to manually add the config.vm.network line